# html text input value appears in brwosers' dump file even after deleting the value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache

In the following code, I'm getting a "sensitive item of information" value from the user in the text field "secret" and in JavaScript I hash the value with md5, then I remove the entered value and submit.
When I go to "Task Manager" and create a memory dump file of the browser, I find the user entered value as a plain text in that file. I want this value to not appear in this file.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />

<form name="secretForm" onsubmit="return encryptSecret();" method="post">    
  <input type="text" class="textfield"  name="secret" id="secret">
  <input type="hidden" id="hiddenSecret">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function encryptSecret(){
   var secret = document.getElementByID("secret");
   var hiddenSecret = document.getElementByID("hiddenSecret");

   hiddenSecret.value = encrypt(secret.value);
   secret.value = "";
   return true;
 }
</script>
```

As you can see I cleared the entered value, and I used "meta tags" to disable cashing, and still the entered value appears in the memory dump file.

Comment: I don’t think there is much you can do about that – trying to influence the actual RAM handling of a client via HTML/JS seems rather far-fetched. And if you think there’s an actual security threat by a malicious 3rd-party programm reading actual RAM content – then the possibility that a simple key logger grabs the value as soon as the user enters it is at least as high, if not even higher IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe Then Why password field value is not there too?